# Displaying an O with an umlaut to properly in html page

Tags: html, mysql

I am trying to get an O with an umlaut to display properly. The text is saved in a MySQL table in a field set to `utf8_unicode_ci.`

Html is using utf-8

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

But I am getting this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect using a UTF8 charset.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_set_charset.asp

Comment: So simple but perfect. Thanks.